# Optimize display method

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

In a form like LedgerJournalTransDaily, there is a field Txt imported from LedgerJournalTrans. 
 Using the JournalNum, I need to go to LedgerJournalTable and get the Name field.

I've written a display method like follows:

```
[SysClientCacheDataMethodAttribute(true)]
public display Name GetLedgerJournalTableName()
{
   LedgerJournalTable ledgerJournalTable;
   Name ret;

   select firstFast firstOnly ledgerJournalTable
       where ledgerJournalTable.JournalNum == this.JournalNum;

   ret = ledgerJournalTable.Name;

   return ret;
 }
```

To be honest, I am not sure if this is fast enough or if there is another way to do it. Please give me a hint.

Comment: The function body should be a one-liner:  
`return LedgerJournalTable::find(his.JournalNum).Name;`

Comment: @JanB.Kjeldsen thanks, i am starting to get the point of this one-liners..

Comment: @JanB.Kjeldsen I don't necessarily agree, If performance is key a `select firstFast firstOnly name from ledgerJournalTable
       where ledgerJournalTable.JournalNum == this.JournalNum;` with an index on journalnum and name as an included column could make sense as you can turn it into a field select. That's paying for performance with readability coins though

Comment: AX ignores your field list anyway as this select is the target of single-record caching. It is not explicitly stated, but when the select can be cached, it does not make sense not to cache all fields. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb314693.aspx

Comment: For another explanation of what @JanB.Kjeldsen mentions, see [When fields lists don't work as expected](http://sashanazarov.blogspot.de/2015/10/when-fields-lists-dont-work.html) by Sasha Nazarov. Also related: [Select Statement Vs Find in Ax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27163459/select-statement-vs-find-in-ax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If performance is a concern, you could try to add the `LedgerJournalTable` as read only datasource to the form with `OnlyFetchActive = Yes`, join it with the `LedgerJournalTrans` data source and add the `Name` field of the new data source to the form design.

But if the journals do not have hundreds of lines and there is no performance problem yet, I would go with the display method. You can always change it later if it becomes a problem and a display method is less invasive than a new data source.

For further reading, take a look at [Tutorial: Caching display methods](http://kashperuk.blogspot.de/2015/05/tutorial-caching-display-methods.html) by Ivan Kashperuk.

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize it by moving select part to static server method on table and when you are selecting define fields you actualy need.

public static server Name getJourName...
...
select Name from ledgerJournalTabel
...

And also you can set false in cache atribute parameter because journal number does not change for transactions in most cases.

Comment: The server method will not buy you anything in this case, as it would defeat client side caching. That is why `find` methods should *not* use the`client` keyword.

Comment: You should still use display method with caching. But in this method you can call your static server method. 'Find' methods return entire record and with display methods this is not needed.